# Florence doesn't show up for text fields in Midori

Tags: debian, lxde

I am having problems with the Florence keyboard displaying (when using the auto hide functionality) when input fields are focused in Midori. It displays when the address bar is focused and strangely enough whenever a password field in the browser gets focus, but not for normal text fields. It also works for other windows such as the terminal but it does not work in iceweasel or any other browsers I've tried (not even for the navigation bar).

The field is reported to be accessible using the accerciser tool.

I am using Debian wheezy, florence 0.6.0-2~bpo70+1, midori 0.4.3+dfsg-0.1, libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 1.8.1-3.4, libatk1.0-0 2.4.0-2. The desktop is LXDE 4. The architecture is 32-bit arm gnueabihf.

Comment: Seems to be a florence issue; managed to compile onboard and it works ok.